# Drawing more than 1 to canvas wont work?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to draw enemy ships to the canvas that will come from the right at a random x being the height of the canvas and a random y past the right side + 1000.

This works fine however I am trying to make it automated and the code runs run it just does not work on screen, only 1 is drawn? Any more info that you need just ask, It's really frying my brain I went line by line for around 3 hours and can't see an issue.

Before I added this code and just called one manually: http://www.taffatech.com/DarkOrbit.html

After I added this code for automatic: (it kinda looks like its overlapping)
http://www.taffatech.com/test.html

Globals:

```
var spawnInterval;
var totalEnemies = 0; //leave as is
var enemies = [];  //array of enemy objects
var spawnRate = 2000; //every 2 seconds
var spawnAmount = 3; //amount of enemies spawned
```

Then my init() calls a startLoop:

```
function startLoop()
{

isPlaying = true;
Loop();
startSpawningEnemies();

}

function stopLoop()
{
isPlaying = false;
stopSpawningEnemies();
}

function Loop()
{
if (isPlaying == true)
{
Player1.draw();
requestAnimFrame(Loop);
 drawAllEnemies();

}
```

then they use these functions:

```
function spawnEnemy(n) //total enemies starts at 0 and every-time you add to array
{
  for (var x = 0; x < n; x++)
   {

     enemies[totalEnemies] = new Enemy();
     totalEnemies++; 
   }

}

function drawAllEnemies()
{

  ClearEnemyCanvas();
  for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
   {
      enemies[1].draw();

   }
}

function startSpawningEnemies()
{
  stopSpawningEnemies();

  spawnInterval = setInterval(function() {spawnEnemy(spawnAmount);}, spawnRate); //this calls spawnEnemy every spawnRate
  /////////spawn 'spawnAmount' enemies every 2 seconds




}


function stopSpawningEnemies()
{

clearInterval(

spawnInterval);
}
```

which in turn calls the Enemy class:

```
function Enemy()  //Object
{

//////Your ships values
this.EnemyHullMax = 1000;
this.EnemyHull = 1000;
this.EnemyShieldMax = 1000;
this.EnemyShield = 347;
this.SpaceCrystalReward = 2684;
this.EnemySpeed = 2; //should be around 6 pixels every-time draw is called by interval, directly linked to the fps global variable
////////////



////Pick Ship
this.type = "Hover";
this.srcX = EnemySrcXPicker(this.type);
this.srcY = EnemySrcYPicker(this.type);

this.enemyWidth = EnemyWidthPicker(this.type);
this.enemyHeight = EnemyHeightPicker(this.type);

this.drawX = EnemydrawXPicker(this.type);
this.drawY = EnemydrawYPicker(this.type);
////


}

Enemy.prototype.draw = function()
{

this.drawX -= this.EnemySpeed;
ctxEnemy.globalAlpha=1;
ctxEnemy.drawImage(spriteImage,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.enemyWidth,this.enemyHeight,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.enemyWidth,this.enemyHeight);

}



function EnemySrcXPicker(type)
{
if (type == "Hover")

    {

        return 906;
      }
}

function EnemySrcYPicker(type)
{
if (type == "Hover")

   {
        return 616;
     }
}

function EnemydrawXPicker(type)
{
if (type == "Hover")

     {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() *  1000) + canvasWidthEnemy;
     }
}

function EnemydrawYPicker(type)
{
if (type== "Hover")

     {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasHeightEnemy - 72));
     }
}


function EnemyWidthPicker(type)
{
if (type == "Hover")

     {
        return 90;
     }
}

function EnemyHeightPicker(type)
{
if (type == "Hover")

     {

        return 72;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
{
   enemies[1].draw();
}
```

should probably be

```
for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
{
   enemies[i].draw();
}
```

...or you'll draw the same enemy over and over.

Comment: That answer was so good I don't even need to read the question to know its right

Comment: Thanks, How I missed that I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

In your drawAllEnemies function, shouldn't

```
enemies[1].draw();
```

be

```
enemies[i].draw();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

When you loop the `enemies` array you should use the index `i` that you setup so that it doesn't continually draw the same element:

```
for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
{
   enemies[i].draw();
}
```